# Input form to demonstrate XSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, xss

I would like to use an input form to demonstrate XSS locally using HTML and JavaScript. The issue is that after passing the parameters via URL and getting it in the JavaScript code, it does not execude. I know that it doesn't execute because I do not reload the DOM.

How am I supposed to do this?

Currently my code looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>XSS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="GET" action="test.html">
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search">
        <input type="submit" value="Senden">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
      <input type="text" name="search" id="search">
      <a href="start.html">Start</a>
</body>
<script>
    function getParameterByName(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    var x = getParameterByName('search');
    $('input[type="text"]').val(x);
</script>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how come you do not reload dom if you send them via URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To demonstrate de XSS vulnerability you need to evaluate the string from the URL  not to set it to the input

*try to test with `<script>alert('test')</script>`*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
      <input type="text" name="search" id="search">
      <a href="start.html">Start</a>
      <script>
    function getParameterByName(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    $(function(){
    var x = getParameterByName('search');
    $('input[type="text"]').after(x);//or eval(x);
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I feel stupid now. I don't know why I did not try this. Have a nice day!